# Convert Range to Sequence

Tags: c#

I have the following range of information (just a small example):

```cs
string range = "1a,2,15-18,15x-16b";
```

I would like to convert it to a `List<string>` that looks like the following:

```
1a
2
15
16
17
18
15x
15y
15z
16a
16b
```

I have seen tons of examples for INT only, but I can't find any examples that have both numbers and letters.

The above is just examples, but the ranges will be much larger, for example 12F-16Z.
Also, the letters may come in as a mixture of lower and upper case.

I am also looking for the most concise way to do this.

Comment: So what have you tried to achieve it? You have an approach that is not concise, because you ask for the most concise way?

Comment: Unless you don't provide what you've tried already, how should anyone here know where *specifically* you need help?

Comment: Apart from this we also have no clues about the specific patterns here. What about upper- and lower-case-characters? Is `A` greater `a`? Is `z` greater `A`? Please read about https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to start from defining the rules first. Are the only options for letters are A-Z? Is there at most one letter? Is `1z4` valid, does it increment to `1z5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we start with a few assumptions

- A single character digit can appear only at the end
- Upper or lowercase can be used, but are not mixed
- single numbers/letter or a range of number/letter with `-` as the separator

Then the following methods should do the trick (Note: Much error handling omitted for brevity and left as an exercise for the reader)

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ParseRangeString(string input) => input.Split(",").SelectMany(CreateRange);  

private static IEnumerable<string> CreateRange(string input)
{
    if(input.Contains("-"))
    {
        var parts = input.Split("-");
        if(char.IsLetter(input.Last()))
        {
            var start = ParseMixed(parts[0]);
            var end = ParseMixed(parts[1]);
            for(var i=start.num;i<=end.num;i++)
            {
                var isLower = char.IsLower(start.c);
                var startC = isLower ? (i == start.num ? (int)start.c : 97 ) : (i == start.num ? (int)start.c : 65);
                var endC = isLower ? (i == end.num ? (int)end.c : 122 ) : (i == end.num ? (int)end.c : 90);
                for(var c=startC;c<=endC;c++)
                {
                    yield return $"{i}{(char)c}";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(var i=int.Parse(parts[0]); i<=int.Parse(parts[1]);i++)
            {
                yield return i.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        yield return input;
    }
}

private static (int num,char c) ParseMixed(string input)
{
    var ch = input.Last();
    var n = int.Parse(input.Substring(0,input.Length-1));
    return (n,ch);
}
```

Usage would be something like

```
var range = ParseRangeString("1a,2,15-18,15x-16b");
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/svg6hk

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. What I gave in the description was all the rules, this works perfectly.